# Cannot insert a row into a store

Tags: extjs, extjs4

On my button click, I want to add a record to the store.

I assume that the way to do this is :

```
onClick: function() {
  store.add({'value': 'asdf'},{'selected':false})
}
```

However I get this error :

> Store.js:973 Uncaught TypeError: me.insert is not a function

My model looks like this :

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'selected', type: 'boolean'},
        {name: 'value', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem. I accidently modified something in Store.js (like putting in a space or something).

Therefore it was deployed with the rest of the code. There was a conflict between **Store.js** and store in **ext-debug-w-comments.js**.

I reverted Store.js and the problem went away.

Comment: You tried to insert two records instead of one: `store.add({'value': 'asdf'},{'selected':false})`